# How to insert an element into all positions in an array using recursion?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I need to accomplish the following task using recursion:

> Declare a function `insert_all_positions`, which takes for arguments: an element, x, and an array, arr. Functions must return an array of arrays, with each array corresponding to arrs with x inserted in a possible position. That is, if arr is the length N, then the result is an array with N + 1 arrays.

For example, the result of `insert_all_positions (10, [1,2,3])` is the array:

```
[[10,1,2,3],
[1,10,2,3],
[1,2,10,3],
[1,2,3,10]]
```

I have this code so far:

```
function insert_all_positions (x, arr) {
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        return arr.concat(x)
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Comment: what means *recursion* in this context?

Comment: I have to call ``insert_all_positions`` in itself.

Comment: yes, that is, how recursion work, but how should it work here?

Comment: That's what I don't know. I don't know how to use recursion in this example.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure recursion.

```js
function f(x, A){
  return A.length ? [[x, ...A]].concat(
    f(x, A.slice(1)).map(e => [A[0]].concat(e))) : [[x]]
}

var x = 10
var A = [1, 2, 3]

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(x, A)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion by cloning, and adding the `x` element at the index (`i`) place, and then calling the function with the same parameters and incremented `i`:

```js
function insert_all_positions (x, arr, i = 0) {
  const clone = [...arr] // clone the array
  
  clone.splice(i, 0, x) // add the item at place i
  
  return i < clone.length - 1 ? // if still under the full length
    [clone, ...insert_all_positions(x, arr, i + 1)] // return current and next item/s
    :
    [clone] // return only current
}

const result = insert_all_positions (10, [1,2,3])

console.log(result)
```

to solve this without recursion, I would use `Array.from()`, and create an array with a length of original `arr` length + 1:

```js
function insert_all_positions (x, arr) {
  return Array.from({ length: arr.length + 1 }, (_, i) => 
    [...arr.slice(0, i), x, ...arr.slice(i)]
  );
}

const result = insert_all_positions (10, [1,2,3])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hmm, `Array.from` for this task is pretty smart. Never really thought to use it - few times I've had to get an array and produce a new one based on it (or at least the contents) but with one or two items less. I've used `reduce` in those cases and terminating it early with `if (cond) return acc` but perhaps `Array.from` is even better.

Comment: Although you can use slice(required length) and then map in this cases.

Comment: Not all the cases, unfortunately - sometimes you need *all* elements of the array but the product has less elements. [Here is a recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59322890/) where I found myself needing sliding windows over an array. So with in input of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` I'd need to produce `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]`, or `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]` so the output size is based on the size of the windows which you can calculate but you can't just `.slice().map()` the array, since you're losing the data for the last windows.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use recursion to do this. But this function should return what you are looking for:

```js
function insert_all_positions (x, arr) {
    const arrays = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        const value = [...arr.slice(0, i), x, ...arr.slice(i)];
        arrays.push(value);
    }
    return arrays
}
```

Comment: But I have to train myself using recursion, so have to use this function to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the result as a parameter that can be passed in. Then you will be able to do the following:

1. (Termination step) if the result is equal to N + 1, you have generated all arrays and you're done.
2. Create a brand new array for the result.
3. Create a new array inserting `x` at an appropriate position

   - You can use the fact that the correct position for `x` is the current length of the result - first it's `0`, next time it's `1`, etc.
4. Construct a new result that uses the array you've created above.
5. (Recursion step) call `insert_all_position` supplying the new result as parameter.

This can look like this

```js
//create an empty array for `result` initially
function insert_all_positions (x, arr, result = []) {
    //terminate - we're done
    if (arr.length + 1 == result.length)
      return result;
    
    //create a new array from `arr` with `x` in its proper place
    const insertIndex = result.length;
    const newArray = arr
      .slice(0, insertIndex)
      .concat(x)
      .concat(arr.slice(insertIndex));
    
    //construct the new result
    const newResult = [...result,  newArray];
    
    //recursive call
    return insert_all_positions(x, arr, newResult)
}

console.log(insert_all_positions(10, [1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure recursion.

> The recursion works from the inserted value `10` as smallest array for an empty array.
>
> The empty array is the exit condition and if no more items of the array are available, only a nested array with the insert value is returned.
>
> For each recursive step, an array with wanted values is extended with the result of the recursive call and this array is mapped with either the insertation value or the first value of the array which is cutted of for the recursive call.
>
> Here this result of the recursion is the right lower matrix.
>
> ```
> result       comment
> -----------  ----------------------------------
>
>          10  insert(10, []), no more recursions
>
>
>       10| 3  insert(10, [3])
>       --+--
>        3|10    > result of the recursion
>
>
>    10| 2  3  insert(10, [2, 3])
>    --+-----
>     2|10  3    \ result of the recursion
>     2| 3 10    /
>
>
> 10| 1  2  3  insert(10, [1, 2, 3])
> --+--------
>  1|10  2  3     \ result of the recursion
>  1| 2 10  3     /
>  1| 2  3 10    /
> ```

```js
function insert(x, array) {
    if (!array.length) return [[x]];
    return [array, ...insert(x, array.slice(1))].map((a, i) => [i ? array[0] : x, ...a]);
}

insert(10, [1, 2, 3]).forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```