# how to validate multiple variables by order in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

`var a, b, c, d, e; // These vars are not required`

Logic:

> a <b <c <d <e => True

- If b = null, then a <c <d <e => True
- If all = null, => True

How to validate the solution for a concise and accurate way? Here I am just example 5 variables but actually more than 20 variables.

Comment: I have seen this post but it did not solve my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269916/what-is-sliding-window-algorithm-examples) over an array with a size of two in order to compare each pair of items. The idea is simple given an array `[a, b, c, d]` you would compare each pair of items

```
1. [a, b, c, d]
   |____|
    a < b

2. [a, b, c, d]
      |____|
       b < c

3. [a, b, c, d]
         |____| 
          c < d
```

[Here is how this technique can be implemented in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57001515). I'd be re-using the part of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59322890/) from that question that uses generators.

All that is left is to implement the comparison. This can be easily generalised for any sort of comparison - less than, greater than, equality, etc, if we accept a function that takes two parameters and compares them. This can then accept any number of parameters to check. Here is how can this work:

```js
function* windowGenerator(inputArray, size) { 
  for(let index = 0; index+size <= inputArray.length; index++) {
    yield inputArray.slice(index, index+size);
  }
}

function toWindows(inputArray, size) {
  //compute the entire sequence of windows into an array
  return Array.from(windowGenerator(inputArray, size))
}

function compareAll(biOperator, ...args) {
  return toWindows(args, 2)
    .every(([a, b]) => biOperator(a, b));
}

//some sample operators
const lt = (a, b) => a < b;
const gt = (a, b) => a > b;
const eq = (a, b) => a === b;

console.log(
  "1 < 3 < 2 =", 
  compareAll(lt, 1, 3, 2)
);
console.log(
  "1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9 =", 
  compareAll(lt, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
);

console.log(
  "1 > 3 > 2 =",
  compareAll(gt, 1, 3, 2)
);
console.log(
  "9 > 8 > 7 > 6 > 5 > 4 > 3 > 2 > 1 =",
  compareAll(gt, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
);
```

We can also remove the need to materialise the entire set of sliding windows before doing the comparison by directly working with the generated sequence:

```js
function* windowGenerator(inputArray, size) { 
  for(let index = 0; index+size <= inputArray.length; index++) {
    yield inputArray.slice(index, index+size);
  }
}

function compareAll(biOperator, ...args) {
  for (const [a, b] of (windowGenerator(args, 2))) {
    if (!biOperator(a, b)) {
      return false
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}

//some sample operators
const lt = (a, b) => a < b;
const gt = (a, b) => a > b;
const eq = (a, b) => a === b;

console.log(
  "1 < 3 < 2 =", 
  compareAll(lt, 1, 3, 2)
);
console.log(
  "1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9 =", 
  compareAll(lt, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
);

console.log(
  "1 > 3 > 2 =",
  compareAll(gt, 1, 3, 2)
);
console.log(
  "9 > 8 > 7 > 6 > 5 > 4 > 3 > 2 > 1 =",
  compareAll(gt, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
);
```